# Write formatted mac address to stringstream

Tags: c++

I have a the following class (only partial, much more fields in a class)

```
class Network{
public:
      string src_ip_;
      string alternative_src_ip_;
      array<unsigned char,6> mac_;
      string toString(){
           stringstream ss;
           ss << src_ip_ << SEPERATOR << alternative_src_ip_ << SEPERATOR ;
           return ss.str();
      }
}
```

I want to add a formatted mac (with :) to the toString method?
Is there a simple way to adopt my printMac method (by generelize or by write new one) that will do this with combined in the << operator

```
void printMac(array<unsigned char, 6> mac) {
    printf("%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", 
            (unsigned char) mac[0], (unsigned char) mac[1],
            (unsigned char) mac[2], (unsigned char) mac[3],
            (unsigned char) mac[4], (unsigned char) mac[5]);
}
```

Comment: Just to be reeeally OCD and nitpicky and generally annoying, i would love it if you'd change your constant to *SEPARATOR :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your use of printf with sprintf and then use it to implement operator<< for ostreams

```
void printMac(array<unsigned char, 6> mac, char (&out)[18]) {
    sprintf(out, "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x", 
            (unsigned char) mac[0], (unsigned char) mac[1],
            (unsigned char) mac[2], (unsigned char) mac[3],
            (unsigned char) mac[4], (unsigned char) mac[5]);
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::array<unsigned char, 6> mac) {
    char buf[18];
    printMac(mac, buf);
    return os << buf << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Stupid question - if i understand correct the last char is for \0 terminator? i used in buf[17] and didn’t have any problem, so why we need to use one with 18 bytes?

Comment: @user1495181 Yes, there's an extra space to hold the null terminator. If you don't have it then sprintf will write outside the array, which causes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 3):

Use the [IO manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip):

```
std::ostringstream s;
unsigned char arr[6] = { 0, 14, 10, 11, 89, 10 };

s << std::hex << std::setfill('0');

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++)
{
    if (i > 0) s << ':';

    // Need to:
    //  - set width each time as it only
    //    applies to the next output field.
    //  - cast to an int as std::hex is for
    //    integer I/O
    s << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain printf-like code, you could try [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/format/).

```
ss << boost::format("%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n") % mac[0] % mac[1] % mac[2] % mac[3] % mac[4] % mac[5];
```